# JQuery Ajax file upload not working properly on clients browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to implement a profile picture upload feature using Ajax and JQuery

I'm able to successfully upload a profile picture to my database on all the machines and mobile devices I have tried. It's **working for me on Chrome, Edge, Firefox, Safari, and even Vivaldi**.

The problem is that my **client who lives in Canada cannot upload their profile picture to the database**. Additionally images in a portrait aspect ratio tend to get rotated sideways. I've been having to ask him to re-register and provide me the console log multiple times because I cannot recreate this bug.

On the profile select page I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require "components.php";
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="766549190582-hnm635v8fd6oaa60nh5tvgpdihrvf922.apps.googleusercontent.com">


    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/token-input-facebook.css" type="text/css" />

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/carousel.css' >

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/visio-theme.css' >

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/navbar.css'>

    <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/font-awesome.css'>

    <?php echo bootstrap_head(); ?>

</head>
<style>
    a {
        -webkit-transition: .25s all;
        transition: .25s all;
    }
    .card {
        overflow: hidden;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        -webkit-transition: .25s box-shadow;
        transition: .25s box-shadow;
    }
    .card:focus, .card:hover {
        box-shadow: 0 5px 11px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    }
    .card-inverse .card-img-overlay {
        background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.85);
        border-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.85);
    }
</style>
<body>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    var $i = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<?php
    echo bootstrap_js();
    echo navbar();
?>
<script>

    var id_token;
    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#register').click(function() {
            $("#idtoken").val(id_token);
        });
    });

    function submit() {
        // send via XHR - look ma, no headers being set!
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.onload = function() {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        };
        xhr.open("post", "./profile.php", true);
    }

    function previewImage(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function(e) {
                var image = new Image;
                image.onload = function () {
                    $('#pic').attr('src', e.target.result);
                };
                image.src = reader.result;
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }


    function getImage() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
    }

    function getuser(id, gUser) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // make a page call to adduser.php
            var profile = gUser.getBasicProfile();
            $("#pic").attr({
                src: profile.getImageUrl()
            });
            $('#name').html(profile.getName());
        })
    }

    function getMatchingSpecialties() {
    }

    function onSignIn(googleUser){
        id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        getuser(id_token, googleUser);
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'POST',
                data: 'idtoken=' + id_token,
                url: 'https://haydenszymanski.me/Visio/php/getmember.php',
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#pic').attr({
                        src: "data:" + result.member_picture_type + ";base64, " + result.member_picture
                    });
                    $('#city').attr({
                        value: result.member_city
                    });
                    $('#country').val(result.member_country);
                    $('#sel1').val(result.member_profession);
                },
                dataType: 'json'
            });
        });
    }

    function signOut() {
        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
        auth2.signOut().then(function () {
            console.log('User signed out.');
        });
    }


</script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <br />
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-3">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 card">
            <form role="form" action="profile.php" id="newForm" runat="server" method="post" >
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1 id="name"></h1>
                        <br />
                        <p>Profile Picture</p>
                        <img src="" id='pic' class="img-thumbnail" alt="profile picture" height="150" width="150"/>
                        <input type="file" id="filesys" value="userfile"/>

                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group" style="margin-right: 20px">
                        <input type="text" id='city' class="form-control" placeholder="City" name="city" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select name="country" class="form-control" required >
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Country</option>
                            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
                            <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                            <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                            <option value="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                            <option value="Angola">Angola</option>

                            <option value="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                            <option value="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                            <option value="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                            <option value="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                            <option value="Heard and McDonald Islands">Heard and Mc Donald Islands</option>
                            <option value="Holy See">Holy See (Vatican City State)</option>
                            <option value="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                            <option value="Hong Kong">Hong Kong</option>
                            <option value="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                            <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                            <option value="India">India</option>
                            <option value="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                            <option value="Iran">Iran (Islamic Republic of)</option>
                            <option value="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                            <option value="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                            <option value="Israel">Israel</option>
                            <option value="Italy">Italy</option>
                            <option value="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                            <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
                            <option value="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                            <option value="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                            <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                            <option value="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                            <option value="Democratic People's Republic of Korea">Korea, Democratic People's Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Korea">Korea, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                            <option value="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                            <option value="Lao">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
                            <option value="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                            <option value="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                            <option value="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                            <option value="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                            <option value="Libyan Arab Jamahiriya">Libyan Arab Jamahiriya</option>
                            <option value="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                            <option value="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                            <option value="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                            <option value="Macau">Macau</option>
                            <option value="Macedonia">Macedonia, The Former Yugoslav Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                            <option value="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                            <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                            <option value="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                            <option value="Mali">Mali</option>
                            <option value="Malta">Malta</option>
                            <option value="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                            <option value="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                            <option value="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                            <option value="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                            <option value="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                            <option value="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                            <option value="Micronesia">Micronesia, Federated States of</option>
                            <option value="Moldova">Moldova, Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                            <option value="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                            <option value="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                            <option value="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                            <option value="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                            <option value="Myanmar">Myanmar</option>
                            <option value="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                            <option value="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                            <option value="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                            <option value="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                            <option value="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                            <option value="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                            <option value="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                            <option value="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                            <option value="Niger">Niger</option>
                            <option value="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                            <option value="Niue">Niue</option>
                            <option value="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                            <option value="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                            <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
                            <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
                            <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                            <option value="Palau">Palau</option>
                            <option value="Panama">Panama</option>
                            <option value="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                            <option value="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                            <option value="Peru">Peru</option>
                            <option value="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                            <option value="Pitcairn">Pitcairn</option>
                            <option value="Poland">Poland</option>
                            <option value="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                            <option value="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                            <option value="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                            <option value="Reunion">Reunion</option>
                            <option value="Romania">Romania</option>
                            <option value="Russia">Russian Federation</option>
                            <option value="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                            <option value="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                            <option value="Saint LUCIA">Saint LUCIA</option>
                            <option value="Saint Vincent">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                            <option value="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                            <option value="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                            <option value="Sao Tome and Principe">Sao Tome and Principe</option>
                            <option value="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                            <option value="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                            <option value="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                            <option value="Sierra">Sierra Leone</option>
                            <option value="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                            <option value="Slovakia">Slovakia (Slovak Republic)</option>
                            <option value="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                            <option value="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                            <option value="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                            <option value="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                            <option value="South Georgia">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                            <option value="Span">Spain</option>
                            <option value="SriLanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                            <option value="St. Helena">St. Helena</option>
                            <option value="St. Pierre and Miguelon">St. Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                            <option value="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                            <option value="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                            <option value="Svalbard">Svalbard and Jan Mayen Islands</option>
                            <option value="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                            <option value="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                            <option value="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                            <option value="Syria">Syrian Arab Republic</option>
                            <option value="Taiwan">Taiwan, Province of China</option>
                            <option value="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                            <option value="Tanzania">Tanzania, United Republic of</option>
                            <option value="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                            <option value="Togo">Togo</option>
                            <option value="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                            <option value="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                            <option value="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                            <option value="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                            <option value="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                            <option value="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                            <option value="Turks and Caicos">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                            <option value="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                            <option value="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                            <option value="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                            <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                            <option value="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                            <option value="United States">United States</option>
                            <option value="United States Minor Outlying Islands">United States Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                            <option value="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                            <option value="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                            <option value="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                            <option value="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                            <option value="Vietnam">Viet Nam</option>
                            <option value="Virgin Islands (British)">Virgin Islands (British)</option>
                            <option value="Virgin Islands (U.S)">Virgin Islands (U.S.)</option>
                            <option value="Wallis and Futana Islands">Wallis and Futuna Islands</option>
                            <option value="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
                            <option value="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                            <option value="Yugoslavia">Yugoslavia</option>
                            <option value="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                            <option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                        </select>
                       </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <br />
                    <label for="sel1">Select Profession</label>
                    <select name="profession" class="form-control" id="sel1" required>
                        <option value="" selected>Profession</option>
                        <option value="optometrist">Optometrist</option>
                        <option value="ophthalmologist">Ophthalmologist</option>
                        <option value="family_physician">Family Physician</option>
                    </select>
                    <div style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
                        <label>Enter some specializations</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="demo-input" name="blah" />
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="src/jquery.tokeninput.js"></script>
                        <script>
                            $i(document).ready(function() {
                                $i("#demo-input").tokenInput("https://haydenszymanski.me/Visio/php/specialties.php", {theme: "facebook"});
                                $i("#demo-input").attr("class", "form-control");
                            });
                        </script>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" id="register" >Register</button>
                </div>
                <input id="idtoken" type="hidden" name="idtoken" value="k">


                <script>
                    var control = document.getElementById("filesys");
                    control.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
                        //$('#register').prop('disable', true);
                        $('#register').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                        var file = control.files[0];
                        var fd = new FormData();
                        fd.append("image", file);
                        fd.append("idtoken", id_token);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: 'https://haydenszymanski.me/Visio/php/update_profile_picture.php',
                            data: fd,
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function() {
                                console.log("first test");
                            }
                        }).done(function(data) {
                            $("#register").removeAttr('disabled');
                            console.log("test");
                            console.log(data);
                        });

                    }, false);

                    $('#filesys').change(function() {
                        previewImage(this);
                    });
                </script>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

The url from that ajax call is not the actual url in the code. **The code to upload the image is done on the file input's change event**.
 Here is the receiving page relevant code.

```
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);
$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);
if ($payload) {
    $fileName = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['image']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['image']['type'];

    $id = $payload['sub'];

    echo update_profile_picture($id, $fileName, $tmpName, $fileType );
    //echo $img_info['content'];
}
else {
}
```

This code uses the function shown here :

```
function update_profile_picture($id, $fileName, $tmpName, $fileType) {
        $conn = new mysqli($GLOBALS['servername'], $GLOBALS['username'], 
        $GLOBALS['password'], 'visio');
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
           die("$conn->connect_errno: $conn->connect_error");
        }

        $fp = fopen($tmpName, 'rb');
        $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
        fclose($fp);

        $sql = "UPDATE member SET member_picture = ?, member_picture_type = ? WHERE member_id = ?";

        $stmt = $conn->stmt_init();
        if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
            echo json_encode(array("Server" => array(
                "Filename" => $fileName,
                "Filetype" => $fileType,
                "Id" => $id
            )), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $content, $fileType, $id);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        else {
            echo "error with upload";
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
```

What baffles me is that I also have it set up for the update_profile_picture function to respond with info about the received picture, but with my clients screenshot of the console log the image type is "", but the image name is the same as it should be. His browser appears to not give all the information the the receiving page, and therefore he can't actually upload the file as a blob to the server.

**UPDATE**: I've looked at other threads, and **while there are similar problems to mine, it's actually working for me**. **The problem is when my client tries to make it work on firefox or edge it will not upload**.

UPDATE 2 : He gave me the version number for edge, but i'm still not replicating the bug. I'm assuming i'm doing the user agent string for the version incorrectly.  It's Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0, Microsoft EdgeHTML 15.15063.

Here is a user agent string that works
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393 . It's a much older version of edge then my client uses, but it still works fine.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but you never closed your `control.addEventListener` code block in the first code snippet. Also in your first snippet, is `fd` meant to be set to new `formData`, instead of `FormData`?

Comment: Hmm. I see the bit of code you're referring to but i'm failing to find where I closed it improperly.

Comment: hmm let me check that bit

Comment: wait. Is formdata() pascal-case?! If this was typed improperly it still works on my browser. Could a later version ignore the improper casing?

Comment: nvm. That was just an error when I was typing into the post. I'll fix that.

Comment: You should probably copy and paste, just so we have the _exact_ code, so the error can be spotted.

Comment: Alright. I'll go ahead and copy and paste the pages code. There. hopefully that provides more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yesturday my client emailed me saying that it works suddenly. I'm not really sure why it didn't work all those other times he has tried, but it now works for him. Thanks for the help guys. Wish I came to a satisfying conclusion though.